# Hibernate mapping where class has multiple rows on one table

Tags: hibernate

I have a hibernate question. My table is of the form:

Id, Date
--       -----
test,     1/1/2012
test,     8/1/2012
test,     29/3/2012
test2,    7/5/2012
test2,    1/1/2012

The primary key is a composite of both these columns.

This maps to objects of the form:

```
class Coll
{
   String id;
   List<Date> entries;
}
```

e.g.

```
aColl
{
   id = test;
   entries = { 1/1/2012, 8/1/2012, 29/3/2012 }
}
```

How would I annotate the object to describe this mapping? I can see how I would do it if I had two tables, one with a row for id, then a key into another table with the entries but not with it all on one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a similar situation and it is hackish. I am not that familiar with annotations but the idea is to make a fake entity which maps to one row and then map the collection to the same table.

```
@Table("MyTable")
@Readonly or @SqlInsert("<noop which returns rowcount == 1 eg insert into temp table>"
@SqlWhere("Date = (SELECT MIN(t.Date) FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Id = Id)")
class Coll
{
   @Column(name="id")
   String id;

   @ElementCollection
   @Table("MyTable")
   @Column(name="id")
   @Element(column="Date")
   @Cascade(AllDeleteOrphan)
   @Lazy(false)
   List<Date> entries;
}
```

feel free to correct the annotations